# moment locale when you using fromNow()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

We are using the function `fromNow()` of moment, but I noticed that this function isn't able to localize his results.

These are my imports:

```
    <SettedWrapper>
      <CueBall size={24} margin="0 10px 0 0" status={status} />
      <div>
        <StatusLabel status={status}>
          <FormattedMessage {...messageStatus} />
        </StatusLabel>
        {console.log(
          'sei qua ---------------------->',
          moment(date)
        .locale(moment.locale('it-IT'))
        .fromNow(),
        )}
        <GrayLabel>
          {moment(date)
            .locale(moment.locale('it-IT'))
            .fromNow()}
        </GrayLabel>
      </div>
    </SettedWrapper>
```

As result of console log I will have this: [image: consoleLogResults]

How can I localize the results of the function `fromNow()`? It's the only part of the site that isn't localized.

---

**Update**

I found this https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/2042, that is related to this bug if can help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to simply pass the locale *identifier* to [`locale(String)`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/instance-locale/) function, so you should use:

```
moment(date).locale('it').fromNow()
```

instead of

```
moment(date).locale(moment.locale('it-IT')).fromNow()
```

Moreover, make sure you have properly loaded the required locale (see [Loading locales in NodeJS](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/loading-into-nodejs/), [Loading locales in the browser](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/loading-into-browser/) and [*Where to use it*](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/use-it/) section of the documentation)

Example:

```js
const date = "2020-04-01";
console.log( moment(date).fromNow() );
console.log( moment(date).locale('it').fromNow() );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: i tried this, and as you can read in the github post, there is an issue with this function. Unluckly i've all my sites translated in 4 languages, but not these line :(

Comment: The linked issue is about already created moment instances that does not take into account updated global locale; in your code you are creating a new moment instance and setting the locale to it. If something like `moment("2020-04-01").locale('it').fromNow()` doesn't work for you, I think that the issue is that you did not imported properly the required locales.

Comment: i think you are right, after several tries i see that normal format date doesn't work. only for this component.